# bs4 python - How can i download images in order, when images are different class. Asking about bs4 python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to use beautifulsoup4. I have an example of webpage similar to reddit.  First, I have images rated in class.
    Example: `<div class="score likes" title="35">35</div>`

I need to download images which are rated for example over 1000.
The problem is that class including images is different ( "title may-blank outbound" or "title may-blank ") . 
If I saved image using  `soup.findall`, I can't check what rate has a specific image.

Thanks for your help

EXAMPLE:

```
...
<div class="score likes" title="1061">1061</div>
...
<A class= "title may-blank outbound" href="example.jpg>
...
<div class="score likes" title="1020">1020</div>
...
<A class= "title may-blank " href="example10.jpg>
...
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML, parents could be a good start

Comment: get all images using `findall` and use `for` loop to check which have rate over 1000. Mostly image and rate should be in some other tag (ie. `div`) so find all those `div`s and later find `rate` and `image` inside every `div` so you get pairs - rate, image - and you can get images with rate over 1000.